# radvd dynamic global prefix subnetting

Tags: networking, ipv6, radvd

Hi my plan is to make two local ipv6 subnets. But i don't have an static global prefix. I know i can use `::/64` in `radvd.conf`. but how to tell radvd to add an subnet after the global prefix somthing like `::1/64` and `::2/64`.

From my isp i get an /56 global prefix, but after every reboot i get an new one. And i'm using debain with eth1 for public connection and eth0.1 and eth0.2 for private networking.

Comment: It depends on the method the `/56` prefixes are assigned to you. For example, I get IPv6 connectivity from my ISP with 6rd tunneling. The settings for the tunnel are delivered via DHCPv4. In the DHCP configuration, I have added a script that creates `radvd.conf` according to the prefix information received in DHCPv4 options and then restarts the daemon.

Comment: i dont even get an ipv4 anymore. i have Carrier-Grade NAT but have full ipv6. so it looks like i had to write an script too.

Comment: Then you have to make a script which executes after IPv6 networking is up. The script would look at your assigned `/56` IPv6 address and generate proper `radvd.conf` based on that prefix. I don't think there is any program that does this.